# python3 increase in salary over previous year

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, boolean

I keep getting an error message:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'float'
I've already changed it to a float, but it didn't work. Please advise!

```
job = {'fireman': 42600, 'librarian': 35000, 'clerk': 23000}

salary = float(job * 1.05 ** years_of_service)

return salary
```

...

Is this the way to go about it, or is there a simpler method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The formula is `salary * 1.05**years`.  Note `**` is exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a map of the post with their salaries; for that, use a dictionary (the only mapping type in Python):

`job_salary = {'engineer': 73200, 'programmer': 48700, 'retail': 23000}`

The formula for adding a bonus is `salary x 1+percentage increase`. Now I leave it up to you to figure out the rest.